# Excel displaying unusual feature on view page

Tags: microsoft-excel

I must have pressed a short-cut or something; now Excel is displaying some weird bar (I don't even know what to call it) below the formula bar (see photo attached). Anyone know what it is and how I can get rid of it?

[image: Weird features...]

Answer (score 2):

Some of your data is **grouped**. In the Data tab, click on Ungroup, and in the dropdown click 'Clear Outline'. You'll be back to normal.

[image]